# Format error with a date in a asp.net bounded field?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-4.0

I have a date in a bounded field as shown below:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="closeDate" HeaderText="End Date"  SortExpression="closeDate" htmlencode="false" dataformatstring="{0:d}" >
  <ItemStyle CssClass="georgeTest"></ItemStyle>
  <HeaderStyle CssClass="georgeTest"> </HeaderStyle> 
</asp:BoundField>
```

I'm trying to format it in this manner: "12/18/2012" with the `dataformatstring` attribute using both the format shown above and `dataformatstring="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}"` they both give me the same value '1/1/0001' all the time and I can't figure out why this happens.

I am working in MS Visual Studio 2010 and ASP.NET 4.0 .

The field is of the `DateTime` type.

Comment: Is your datafield, closeDate, a DateTime type?

Comment: I edited my question with the answer.

Comment: Trying to think of other things to check, because it should work if the field is a DateTime field.  Are your casting closeDate to text in your SQL statement?  Also what database are you using?  SQL Server?

Comment: No casting was done and yes I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: Apparently there are some known "issues" with this - for a full answer and example of how to get it working see this article here http://peterkellner.net/2006/05/24/how-to-set-a-date-format-in-gridview-using-aspnet-20using-htmlencode-property/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference going forward I've posted the link content from my comment as the answer:

How To Set a Date Format In GridView Using ASP.NET 2.0 (Using HtmlEncode Property)

[Posted by Peter Kellner in .Net 2.0, ASP.NET 2.0](http://peterkellner.net/2006/05/24/how-to-set-a-date-format-in-gridview-using-aspnet-20using-htmlencode-property/)
(AKA, the DataFormatString="{0:M-dd-yyyy}" Problem)

A very common desire is to set a column of a GridView to display just the month, day and year of a DateTime type. The problem is the by default, the HtmlEncode property of the BoundField attribute (

```
<columns>
  <asp:BoundField headertext="CreationDate" dataformatstring="{0:M-dd-yyyy}" 
       datafield="CreationDate"  />
</columns>
```

You have two choices to make this work as you would expect. The first choice is to simply set HtmlEncode to false as follows:

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="server" >
<columns>
  <asp:BoundField headertext="CreationDate" dataformatstring="{0:M-dd-yyyy}" 
       datafield="CreationDate"  HtmlEncode="false" />
</columns>
```

The second choice is to make the column a template and simply set the format string directly in the Label or Text Fields as follows.

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView3" runat="server" >
 <columns>
  <asp:TemplateField headertext="CreationDate" >
   <edititemtemplate>
    <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" Label.Text='<%# Eval("CreationDate", "{0:M-dd-yyyy}") %>'>
    </asp:Label>
   </edititemtemplate>
   <itemtemplate>
    <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" Label.Text='<%# Bind("CreationDate", "{0:M-dd-yyyy}") %>'>;
    </asp:Label>
   </itemtemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
 </columns>
</asp>
```